Problem to record audio in Mac using Flutter and Record plugin
This code works perfect in Web, but in Mac it prints only zeros. What is the problem?
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:file_selector/file_selector.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:record/record.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Audio Recorder with Stream'),
        ),
        body: AudioRecorderWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AudioRecorderWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AudioRecorderWidgetState createState() => _AudioRecorderWidgetState();
}

class _AudioRecorderWidgetState extends State<AudioRecorderWidget> {
  final AudioRecorder _record = AudioRecorder();
  bool _isRecording = false;
  String? _filePath;

  Stream<Uint8List>? audioStream;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _record.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _startRecording() async {
    print('start1');
    try {
      bool hasPermission = await _record.hasPermission();
      if (!hasPermission) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(content: Text('Microphone permission is required')),
        );
        return;
      }

      audioStream = await _record.startStream(RecordConfig(
          encoder: AudioEncoder.pcm16bits,
          sampleRate: 16000,
          bitRate: 128000,
          numChannels: 1));

      audioStream?.listen((Uint8List data) {
        print('sink data: $data');
      });

      print('start2');

      setState(() {
        _isRecording = true;
      });
    } catch (e, s) {
      print('Exception: $e\nStack Trace: $s');
    }
  }

  Future<void> _stopRecording() async {
    print('stop1');
    try {
      if (await _record.isRecording()) {
        await _record.stop();
        print('stop2');
        setState(() {
          _isRecording = false;
        });

        print('stop4: $_filePath');
      } else {
        print('Recording was not active.');
      }
    } catch (e, s) {
      print('Exception: $e\nStack Trace: $s');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: _isRecording ? null : _startRecording,
            child: Text('Start Recording'),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: _isRecording ? _stopRecording : null,
            child: Text('Stop Recording'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

